# Lightning component to render a rich text field unescaped

Tags: lightning-aura-components, richtextarea, escape

Trying to do something fairly simple I think and query a FeedItem record then display its body in a lightning component. Issue I have is that I cant work out how to display the body unescaped.

In the component as before I am  even trying to fling in an escape = false attribute but isnt doing the trick.

(If this was visualforce Id use the escaped= false attribute on apex:output text but that doesnt seem to be availbe here).

**Apex Controller Method**

```
@AuraEnabled
public static FeedItem getChatterPost(Id parId) {
    return [SELECT Id, Title, Body, Type, ParentId, Parent.Name 
            FROM FeedItem
            WHERE ParentId = :parId
            LIMIT 1];
}
```

**Component**

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global"  controller="PortalCaseAlertsController">
<ltng:require styles="/resource/SLDS203/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-ltng.css" /> 
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
<aura:attribute name="chatterPost" type="FeedItem" />
<aura:attribute name="chatterPostList" type="FeedItem[]" />

<article class="slds-card slds-card">
    <div class="slds-card__header slds-grid">
        <header class="slds-media slds-media--center slds-has-flexi-truncate">
            <div class="slds-media__body slds-truncate">
                <h2>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-text-link--reset">
                        <span class="slds-text-heading--small">Announcements</span>
                    </a>
                </h2>
            </div>
        </header>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-card__body slds-text-align--center">
        <div class="uiOutputRichText"  escape="false" linkify="true" >
            {!v.chatterPost.Body}    
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-card__footer"> ... </div>
</article>
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Did you try

```
<ui:outputRichText aura:id="outputRT" value="{!v.chatterPost.Body}" />
```

Which would result in the proper output

I believe they way you are doing it, is the final output of the `ui` component but with the escaped version of the value.

You could also do

```
<div class="uiOutputRichText" linkify="true" >
     <aura:unescapedHtml value="{!v.chatterPost.Body}"/>
</div>
```

> To output pre-formatted HTML, use aura:unescapedHTML. For example,
>   this is useful if you want to display HTML that is generated on the
>   server and add it to the DOM. You must escape any HTML if necessary or
>   your app might be exposed to security vulnerabilities.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_html.htm

Comment: Great thanks, dumb of me to miss that. The only defense I can offer for doig so is that i the SF component reference for ui:outputRichText https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_ui_outputRichText.htm  the example they give is just as I had it, a div with a class. 

In retrospect that is really inconsistent with the other components so I should have spotted but it threw me.

Comment: That was an example of what the tag compiled to. Maybe that example should have been put at the end of the article.

Comment: @Doug - Yea, that got me at first too, you have to really read and you will see the following: `which results in the following HTML` - **The docs do not even give an example of the *"correct"* usage** - If you click "next" the `ui:outputText` give a proper example of it and is how the doc for the rich text should be. I submitted doc feedback in case anyone is listening

Comment: Yeah I see, my bad going straight to the code example. Opening 5 or so other pages on ui comps the rest all do follow the patter of example of component then what tag compiles to so this page is a bit inconsistent (still should have been obvious to spot though!)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **lightning:formattedRichText value="{!v.messageAttributeName}"**

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:formattedRichText/example

Answer (score 0):

This is just a div with an expression set to its nodeValue:

```
<div class="uiOutputRichText"  escape="false" linkify="true" >
   {!v.chatterPost.Body}   <!-- not how you include a child component --> 
</div>
```

The only thing that will happen here is that `v.chatterPost.Body` will be set as the textContent of the div.

Although you are declaring the div to have a class equal to "uiOutputRichText", the process of compiling component markup to html isn't hooked into class names, but into declaring the right xml namespace and tag:

```
<ui:outputRichText value="{!v.chatterPost.Body}"/> <!-- this works -->
```

(The `escape="false"` attribute is part of VisualForce, not Aura)

For more info, see https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_ui_outputRichText.htm?search_text=rich%20text